# Add additional Magento stock status

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

Does anyone have an idea on how to add additional stock status in Magento 1.6.2?  Currently there is either In Stock or Out of Stock.  I am trying to get my configurable products set up, and as such need the ability to have the drop down select options available to the user on the product page.

We have products that truly are "In Stock", so no problem with that one.  We have other products that need a lead time, so I changed "Out of Stock" to read "Call for Availability".  The problem with that is, it's really the Out of Stock option in the products settings page.

Being that we have to select the item is out of stock, it will not populate or display the select boxes on the configurable products page.

Is there a way to add another stock status within the product settings page?  Without paying $250US for an extension?  Or is there a way to flag the current Out of Stock option to be in stock as far as the script is concerned?  We have no other reason to use the Out of Stock option, so modifying it isn't a problem in this case.

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 0):

We discussed that last week in the IRC and this is not that easy. The problem is, that the stock-status is used as a boolean value and because of that, it is not a good idea to only add a third one. You have to change a lot of more things.

I recommend to add an attribute an use this to add the status.

Comment: I ended up using a paid extension, found one for $50, which was well worth it considering the time involved with other options :-)